# Registering Identity Framework UserStore with Simpleinjector for AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, simple-injector

I have a situation where I want to Use custom UserStore from Identity framework . So my controller looks something like this .

```
public AccountController()
: this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new MyUserStore()))
{
}
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
      UserManager = userManager;
}
```

Now Simpleinjector doesnt allow multiple constructors . It can allows to register those classes with exactly one constructor  . How am I supposed to resolve this when the situation is like that of the above . with Simpleinjector registration .

Comment: Prevent having multiple constructors: It's [an anti-pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Injector requires one public constructor.  It cannot determine which one to use at runtime if you have more than one.

The solution is a design issue - why do you need more than one constructor?  This can be answered by asking yourself...

Do i want SimpleInjector to create instances of IUserStore or should this be done manually?

I would assume it to be the former, given that it makes the AccountController difficult to test if you are not allowing dependencies to be injected.

The following configuration (usually stored in App_Start/SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs) will allow IUserStore instances to be of your custom type: MyUserStore, and will be injected into IUserManager if the constructor expects this...

```
container.Register<IUserStore, MyUserStore>();    
container.Register<IUserManager<ApplicationUser>, UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Comment: +1. Great answer. Note that you can also do `container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IUserManager<>), typeof(UserManager<>))` if you need to map many versions of `IUserManager<T>` to `UserManager<T>`. For this you need to include the `SimpleInjector.Extensions` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

After Suggestion of Baldy And Steven I ended up with the solution as :

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<Users, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<Users, Guid> Store)
        : base(Store)
    {        
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserStore 
    : UserStore<Users, Roles, Guid, UserLogins, UserRoles, Claims>,
    IUserStore<Users,Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(RemsContext Context)
        : base(Context)
    {          
    }
}
```

And As for Simpleinjector Configuraiton I have registered the above as

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext, RemsContext>();

container.Register<UserManager<Users, Guid>, ApplicationUserManager>();
container.Register<RoleManager<Roles, Guid>, ApplicationRoleManager>();

container.Register<IUserStore<Users, Guid>, 
    UserStore<Users, Roles, Guid, UserLogins, UserRoles, Claims>>();
container.Register<IRoleStore<Roles, Guid>, RoleStore<Roles, Guid, UserRoles>>();
```

This is my implementation The same goes for `RoleManager` as well. And the implementation when calling the above as

```
public AccountsController(ApplicationUserManager _userManager,
    ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager)
{
    this.UserManager = _userManager;           
    this.RoleManager = _roleManager;
}
```

I would Like to invite both @Steven and @Baldy to comment on this, if the approach is correct.

Comment: @Steven Please comment on the approach if it seems fine . I have followed Baldy's suggestion However with some small tweaks here with context class

Comment: It's hard to say much useful on this. You seem to apply the [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) correctly and only inject what you need directly, which is good. I'm however a bit worried about your base classes `UserManager` and `UserStore`. Its hard to say, but you might be violating the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) in those base classes. If you're in doubt, ask a question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)and place a link in the comments.

Comment: Along the lines of what Steven has already mentioned - your ApplicationUserStore looks quite 'busy', which could indicate violation of SRP.  This may simply be because you havent discovered how to use OpenGenerics with SimpleInjector.  Read about those here - http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios   If OpenGenerics doesnt apply to to that it may be worth looking at the role of ApplicationUserStore and seeing if its responsibilites can be broken down somewhat. The design of that class probably best dealt with as a question of its own